# XCode 4 - Warning for - (void)renderInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, warnings

I have this code:

```
+ (UIImage*) someImageMethod:(UIImage*)originalImage {
    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:originalImage];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempImageView.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    ...    

    [tempImageView.layer renderInContext:context];

    ...    
}
```

This generates a persistent warning: `No '-RenderInContext' method found.`

Why such an error? How may I make it disappear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure you **`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`**, and add the framework to your Project.